# Bootstrap 4 sticky dropdown and sticky nav overlapping problem

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here is my problem: How can I make the dropdown button menu appear in front of the vertical menu? If I click on the dropdown, the vertical (blue) menu is the main one to click. The problem has suddenly appeared after adding sticky-top class to both menus. I know I could probably force z-index but it might clash with bootstrap's things like modal.

[image]

```
<div class="dropdown sticky-top">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    
    <div class="container sticky-top" style="top: 4em">
      <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="col-9">
  
    <div class="container border m-5">
    test
    </div>
    <div class="container border m-5">
    test
    </div>
    <div class="container border m-5">
    test
    </div>
    <div class="container border m-5">
    test
    </div>
    <div class="container border m-5">
    test
    </div>
    <div class="container border m-5">
    test
    </div>
    <div class="container border m-5">
    test
    </div>
    <div class="container border m-5">
    test
    </div>
    <div class="container border m-5">
    test
    </div>
    <div class="container border m-5">
    test
    </div>
    <div class="container border m-5">
    test
    </div>
    <div class="container border m-5">
    test
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zwfcds9t/31/

(I needed to re-run the fiddle to make the dropdown menu working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `z-index` property higher than the sticky sidebar.

```
.dropdown.sticky-top {
    z-index: 1021;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To Avoid Overlapping You'll need to Layer each on separate `z-index`.

for you the fix would be:

```
.dropdown.sticky-top {
    z-index: 99;
}
```